# Post to a specific thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to post something back to a specific (calling) thread, perhaps by thread ID.
DoStuff() was working when it ran on the UI thread, but that is no longer an option for me.

```
void DoStuff()
{
    long origThreadID_A = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    Log.d(TAG, "origThreadID (A): " + origThreadID_A);

    new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            //Do something on new thread

            <[WHAT_GOES_HERE?]>(new Runnable()  //This used to be 'activity.runOnUiThread', 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    long origThreadID_B = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    Log.d(TAG, "origThreadID (B): " + origThreadID_B);

                    //Do something on original thread
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

How to you post and/or run something on a specific thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a Handler on that thread and post the runnable to that handler.  If you want to be able to post to a thread by id, you'll have to maintain a map of thread ids to Handlers somewhere.  Remember that any thread that uses a handler must at some point call Looper.loop().

Comment: Isn't Looper.loop() a blocking call?  How do I do it without blocking the DoStuff() thread?  When I ran DoStuff() on the UI thread, I could post to it without making the UI thread block.

Comment: Looper.loop starts an event loop.  So it will never return but it isn't strictly blocking-  you just have to write your thread to work on events.  Of course you'd have to do that for any method of posting to a thread, Android just set up the UI thread for you (the UI thread has a Looper with Looper.loop called as part of initialization).